# Unable to dereference double pointer in c

Tags: c, dereference, double-pointer

The output of this code is 20 20 10. The first 20 is easy to understand. But I am unable to understand how function `change1` and `change2` are accessing the variable b.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int a = 5, b = 10;
void change1(int *p);
void change2(int **pp);
main( )
{
    int x=20, *ptr=&x;
    printf("%d  ",*ptr);
    change1(ptr);
    printf("%d  ",*ptr);
    change2(&ptr);
    printf("%d\n",*ptr);
}
void change1(int *p)
{
    p = &a;
}
void change2(int **pp)
{
    *pp = &b;
}
```

Comment: The `change2` function is accessing `b` because you use `&b` in it. Is that what you intended to write?

Comment: `void change1(int *p)
{
    p = &a;
}` does not affect `ptr` in `change1(ptr);`

Comment: No. sorry if I was not clear. I am unable to understand which pointer is accessing which other variable and how finally value of b (10) is being shown in output.

Answer (score 2):

> But I am unable to understand how function `change1` and `change2` are accessing the variable `b`.

There is a misunderstanding of what `change1` does.

It changes where `p` points to but that change is local to the function. It does not change where `ptr` points to in `main` since the pointer is passed by value. `change1` does not have any code that accesses the variable `b`. It's not clear to me whey you think it does.

In `change2`, you are changing where the pointer points to, to `b`. The change affects where `ptr` points to in `main` since you are passing the address of `ptr` to `change2` and you are changing where that dereferenced pointer points to.

Answer (score 1):

In change1, p is a pointer to int that is passed by value.   Assigning a value to p in change1 therefore has no effect because p is local to change1.   This is the reason for the 2nd 20.

In change2, pp is a pointer to a pointer to int.  It too is passed by value, but this time dereferencing pp (*pp) gives access to the location of the pointer (ptr), and it is into this location that the address of b (&b) is stored.

Answer (score 0):

```
void change1(int *p)
{
    p = &a;
}
```

The variable p is assigned with the address of a, but this is only valid within the function. p acts as a `local variable` within the function `change1`. After this function terminates, the pointer ptr would still be pointing at  x(=20). This is the reason behind the second 20.

```
void change2(int **pp)
{
    *pp = &b;
}
```

But this, is one of the correct ways to make changes to a pointer variable within the function so that it would still be valid outside. `pp` acts as a pointer pointing to the original `ptr` variable. As a result, ptr will end up pointing at b(=10) after change 2 terminates. This is the reason behind your third 10.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke `change1()` function, you're passing the pointer `ptr` as an argument. Let's suppose `ptr = 0xcafebabe`, and obviously `*ptr = 20`.
 Under the hood, you're writing the value `0xcafebabe` on the stack, and the `change1()` function will only overwrite this value with `&a` on the stack frame corresponding to this function.
In the second case, you're passing a pointer to `ptr` as an argument. Let's suppose this pointer `new_ptr` has a value of `0xdeadbeef`.
 In this case, `*new_ptr = 0xcafebabe`  and you overwrite `0xcafebabe` with `&b` (hence you are changing where the pointer is *pointing*.